# The requested URL / was not found on this server in Google App Engine for Vue .js

Tags: vue.js, google-app-engine, vue-router

I have deployed code in Google app engine server with route mode changes from `mode: 'hash'` to `mode: 'history'`. After this change, I am getting this error.

`Error: Not Found The requested URL /login was not found on this server.`

Here is route.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import DefaultContainer from '../containers/DefaultContainer'

// Views
import Dashboard from '../views/Dashboard'
import Login from '../views/login/Login'
import ForgotPassword from '../views/password/ForgotPassword'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    mode: 'hash',
    // mode: 'history',
    linkActiveClass: 'open active',
    routes: [
        {
          path: '/',
          redirect: '/dashboard',
          name: 'Home',
          component: DefaultContainer,
          children: [
            {
                {
                  path: '/dashboard',
                  name: 'Dashboard',
                  component: Dashboard,
                  meta: {
                    requiresAuth: true,
                    title: 'Dashboard'
                  }
                },
            }
        },
        {
          path: '/login',
          name: 'Login',
          component: Login,
          meta: {
            title: 'Dashboard Login'
          }
        },
        {
          path: '/forgot-password',
          name: 'ForgotPassword',
          component: ForgotPassword,
          meta: {
            title: 'Forgot Password'
          }
        },
        .
        .
        .
    ]
})
```

Here is app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*)
```

Can anybody please help me...

Comment: It seems like a problem with the defined routes, please post your vue-router configuration file. Also include some details about what action are you performing when you get the error and if you have been able to locally run your app without App Engine.

Comment: @Emmanuel i have added route file in question description. after change in route  mode, it's working perfectly in locally but after when i deployed on app-engine server & hit the domain then i get the error.

Comment: I apologize to ask by pieces but also can you show post folder structure? It seems that there might be a routing problem while trying to link the routes from Vuejs with the ones defined on the app.yaml file

Comment: from the  route.js I can configure out the application is the vue.js app. however in the app.yaml file, the runtime shows python. for my understanding, it should be at least Node.js since they are both Javascript. As the vue.js have not been implemented as the native runtime for App Engine, however, there is a walk around solution which is, deploying Vue.js app to Google App Engine with Cloud Build. You can refer for this [Link](https://medium.com/@brian.young.pro/how-to-deploy-vue-js-app-to-google-cloud-with-cloud-build-ad104bb1cf60) for tutorials.

Comment: @ShawnDiWu the runtime in this case isn't important, because vuejs is frontend framework that runs on the client PC not in the server, while the runtime is used normally as the backend and run inside the server, so as long as the OP is defining it as a statics files it should work